# leer txt, separado por | desde nodejs convertirlo en objeto para enviar por post

Tags: javascript, nodejs

buenas tengo la siguiente pregunta. Tengo un txt, que viene separado por "|", entonces vienen 6 datos entre los "|" asi

```
1 | Argentina |Y|CODIGO POSTAL |CAPITAL|ESTADOS
```

Yo quisiera convertir cada una de estas posiciones separadas por los "|", sea una posicion dentro de un array ejemplo

```
0 |   1       |2|3             |4      |5
1 | Argentina |Y|CODIGO POSTAL |CAPITAL|ESTADOS
```

y trabajarlos dentrode una array

```
Mi codigo

ReadFile = () => {
try {
    // read contents of the file
    const data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'UTF-8');

    // split the contents by new line
    const lines = data.split("\\|", 6)

    // print all lines
    lines.forEach((lines) => {
        let arr = [] = lines
        console.log(arr[2]); ---> deberia retornar 'Y'
   });
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
}
```

agradecido con sus comentarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer paso es obtener línea, separando los datos por salto de línea `\n` y después recorrer para separar los datos por barra vertical `\|`, nota que solo se requiere un caracter de escape y no dos como tenías.

```js
let data = `0 |   1       |2|3             |4      |5
1 | Argentina |Y|CODIGO POSTAL |CAPITAL|ESTADOS`;

// Separar por salto de línea
const lines = data.split("\n");

// Recorrer todas las líneas
lines.forEach(line => {
    // Separar datos:
    // .split() es para separar
    // .map() es para recorrer el nuevo arreglo
    // .trim() elimina espacios al inicio y final
    const datos = line.split("\|", 6).map(a => a.trim());
    console.log(datos);
});
```

Probablemente, los datos que publicaste tienen espacios para formatear en la pregunta, de ser así, puedes eliminar `.map(a => a.trim())`

Comment: muchas gracias pana <3

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con la funcion "split" que se usa en los strings, con esa función le mandamos como parámetro el delimitador, en este caso seria "|".
El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
// print all lines
lines.forEach((line) => {
  let arr = line.split("|");
  console.log(arr[2]);
});
```